# Prove that $\gcd(2^{2^{22}}+1,2^{2^{222}}+1)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, fermat-numbers

The great common divisor (gcd) of $2^{2^{22}}+1$ and $2^{{2}^{222}}+1$ is

*My work*,

\begin{align}
F_{n}-2&= 2^{2^{n}}+1-2 \\
&=(2^{2^{n-1}}+1)(2^{2^{n-2}}+1)(2^{2^{n-2}}-1)\\
&=(2^{2^{m}}+1)(2^{2^{m}}-1)(2^{2^{m-n-1}}+1)\ \ \ [\text{ where }  m \geq n]
\end{align}

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2826805/simplifying-gcdax-1-ay-1)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687760/prove-that-gcd-leftna1-nb1-right-divides-n-gcda-b1/3687796#3687796

Comment: In your edit it appears that you go from "$gcd(n^{a}+1,n^{b}+1)$ divides $n^{gcd(a,b)}+1$" to "$gcd(n^{a}+1,n^{b}+1)$ equals $n^{gcd(a,b)}+1$" without justification.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a general result that $\gcd(F_n,F_m)=1$ whenever $m\neq n$

**Proof:** Let $\mathrm{WLOG}$ $m>n$. Then we have,
$$F_m-2=(2^{2^{m-1}}-1)(2^{2^{m-1}}+1)=(2^{2^{m-1}}-1)F_{m-1}$$ Proceeding this way we get,
$$F_m-2=F_{m-1}F_{m-2}\cdots F_0=MF_n$$ for some $M\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore $\gcd(F_m,F_n)\mid2$. Since $F_m,F_n$ are odd we have $\gcd(F_m,F_n)=1$. In particular $\gcd(2^{2^{22}}+1,2^{2^{222}}+1)=1$.

Done!

Comment: Why  am I not getting ans using that formula?

Comment: You have some error in computation. Check once again.

Comment: $$F_{n}-2= 2^{2^{n}}+1-2 =(2^{2^{n-1}}+1)(2^{2^{n-2}}+1)(2^{2^{n-2}}-1)=\color{red}{
(2^{2^{m}}+1)(2^{2^{m}}-1)(2^{2^{m-n-1}}+1)}$$ The red part deduction is incorrect.

Comment: thanks, got it!